# Action parameter with possible multiple args

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I have a `WaitAndRun` function. I want this method to be very generic.

```
public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T>(float time, Action<T> action, object arg)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action((T)arg);
}
```

It works perfectly with the following example:

```
void an_action(int x)
{
    Debug.Log(x);
}
//...
WaitAndRun<int>(1, an_action, 2);
```

The problem is I want to use the same definition when I need multiple args as well. How can I make this function support calling single and multiple args at the same time? For instance:

```
void another_action(int x, int y);
```

If I use`object[] args` instead of `object arg`, I am not sure about how to modify the remaining part.

Edit: changed func to action

Comment: Have you considered the [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - It wouldn't be type-safe.

Comment: Side point: why don't you use `IEnumerator<TReturn>` and return `yield return new WaitForSeconds<TReturn>(...` In fact why is this an `IEnumerator` anyway if you don't use it with a `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative suggestion: Use lambda expressions and their ability to capture local variables:

```
public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun(float time, Action action)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action();
}
```

Usage:

```
WaitAndRun(1, () => an_action(2));
WaitAndRun(1, () => another_action(2, 3));
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I am looking for, awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the standard way it is done in the framework:

```
public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T>(float time, Action<T> action, T arg)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2>(float time, Action<T1, T2> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
{
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8, T9 arg9)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8, T9 arg9, T10 arg10)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8, T9 arg9, T10 arg10, T11 arg11)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10, arg11);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8, T9 arg9, T10 arg10, T11 arg11, T12 arg12)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10, arg11, arg12);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8, T9 arg9, T10 arg10, T11 arg11, T12 arg12, T13 arg13)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10, arg11, arg12, arg13);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8, T9 arg9, T10 arg10, T11 arg11, T12 arg12, T13 arg13, T14 arg14)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10, arg11, arg12, arg13, arg14);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8, T9 arg9, T10 arg10, T11 arg11, T12 arg12, T13 arg13, T14 arg14, T15 arg15)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10, arg11, arg12, arg13, arg14, arg15);
}

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16>(float time, Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8, T9 arg9, T10 arg10, T11 arg11, T12 arg12, T13 arg13, T14 arg14, T15 arg15, T16 arg16)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10, arg11, arg12, arg13, arg14, arg15, arg16);
}
```

Note that `Action<...>` is defined only to 16 parameters.

I also changed `func` to `action` as a function strictly returns a value and I wanted to be very clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am looking for a way of defining only one time, similar to:

public static IEnumerator WaitAndRun<object[]>(float time, Action<object[]> action, object[] args)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    action(args);
}

I know this example doesn't work ^ but I am looking for something similar. Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: @nadirg - Yes, understood. But this is how it's done in the .Net framework itself.

Comment: I feel a bit hard done by with the down-vote. This is literally how `Func<...>` and `Action<...>` are defined in the framework.